# How do i fetching list of records in QCombo BOX from Sqlite3 database in PYQT5 Python using QSQL

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qcombobox, qsqldatabase

I want to get list of records from database table.
These are the values of two column name "id" and "lable" inserted into database.

```
INSERT INTO "phone_number_type" VALUES(1,'Home');
INSERT INTO "phone_number_type" VALUES(2,'Work');
INSERT INTO "phone_number_type" VALUES(3,'Mobile');
INSERT INTO "phone_number_type" VALUES(4,'Mistress');
INSERT INTO "phone_number_type" VALUES(5,'Meth Dealer');
```

I want to get only column name "lable" into QComboBox.
here is my code:

```
import sys
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtSql
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from combobox import Ui_MainWindow


class fetchrec(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("ttest.db")
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("phone_number_type")
        self.comboBox.setModelColumn(self.model.fieldIndex("lable"))
        self.comboBox.setModel(self.model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    userins = fetchrec()
    userins.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `self.model.select()`.

Comment: but i am only getting one row "home".how do i get all list?

Comment: @user3135049 Have you checked that your database has that data? That is the method that I commonly use to fill a QComboBox and I have never had problems, obviously you should use what ekhumuro mentions.

Comment: you could share your .db

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15kie4cTPe-G0NdVYysKMHjU8PRaLShs1?usp=sharing

Comment: above is shared link to my project

Comment: @user3135049. Set the model ***before*** setting the model column.

Comment: Thanks its working.Though the first field in combo box in blank why is that?